# Show ajax loading symbol only on long loads

Tags: jquery, ajax

We use code similar to this

```
var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $loading.show();
})
.ajaxStop(function () {
   $loading.hide();
});
```

On our page we have many ajax calls and the loading symbol pops up way too often.  Is there a way to have it only show if the ajax call is over 3 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a timer, and clear the timer when the ajax is finished in case it hasn't fired yet.

```
var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
var timeOutHandler;
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
   timeOutHandler = setTimeout(function(){$loading.show();}, 3000);
})
.ajaxStop(function () {
   clearTimeout(timeOutHander);
   $loading.hide();
});
```

Comment: Looks like you used `clearInterval` instead of `clearTimeout`

Comment: If you correct the typo 'timeOutHander' in Line 2, I think the solution is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

off the top of my head doesn't jquery have `.delay()`?

```
var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
$(document)
   .ajaxStart(function () {
    $loading.delay(3000).show();
})
.ajaxStop(function () {
   $loading.hide();
});
```

Comment: I don't think delay would work here because it can't be cancelled.  So if the ajax is completed  in 2 seconds, the loading animation will appear 1 second after it loads and will never hide.

Answer (score 0):

Try using timeouts, like this

```
var $loading = $('#loadingDiv').hide();
var loadingTimer;
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    // clear existing if any
    clearTimeout(loadingTimer);
    loadingTimer = setTimeout(showLoading, 3000)
})
.ajaxStop(function () {
    // clear timeouts that haven't yet happened
    clearTimeout(loadingTimer);
    $loading.hide();
});
function showLoading(){
    $loading.show();
}
```

Quick and clean

Answer (score 0):

there is a nice little plug-in here

https://github.com/bstaley/aspectorientedajax/blob/master/aOAjax.js

you can pass it a pre and post function. It will hook into ajax requests and keep track of outstanding request. so for example if you had 5 ajax calls overlapping each other it could show on the first and hide after the last. It's vanilla JavaScript, only needs to be called once and it's as simple as `new AjaxAspect(showFunc,hideFunc);`

here is a fiddle that should show you exactly how this would be achieved. http://jsfiddle.net/bstaley/9VaeC/